# Disable attach documents to completion email

Tags: docusignapi

In the New Docusign view we are able to uncheck "attach documents to completion email" and click on save. But the save button in the signing setting is not responding. We are able to do this successfully in demo account and trying to do the same in the prod account.

Comment: Not responding mean, is it disabled?

Comment: It did not throw an error and it did not save and success message is also not shown

Comment: did you try log out, closing browser and trying again?

Comment: I just received a reply from docusign, "attach documents to completion email" should be done at the docusign end

Comment: I think that's only needed if you do not have this option available in your subscription plan with DocuSign. But you mentioned that you can see that setting to check/uncheck that checkbox, so it should be controlled on your end as well. Can you check with DS support that why its visible to you to check/uncheck the option?